# Unable to connect to example.com:25 (Connection timed out) using smtp

Tags: php, validation, email

i'm using this google class and code https://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/ to check an array of emails and get which is real and which isn't.

But im getting an error:

unable to connect to example.com:25 (Connection timed out)
Error: Could not connect to a valid mail server for this email address: @example.com

I didn't find anything like that and i already have disabled firewall and etc...

Well still not working:

```
Array
(
    [mx4.hotmail.com] => 5
    [mx3.hotmail.com] => 5
    [mx2.hotmail.com] => 5
    [mx1.hotmail.com] => 5
    [hotmail.com] => 0
)
try mx4.hotmail.com:25
<<<
220 BAY004-MC6F11.hotmail.com Sending unsolicited commercial or bulk e-mail to Microsoft's computer network is prohibited. Other restrictions are found at http://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/anti-spam.mspx. Wed, 24 Sep 2014 10:15:49 -0700 
>>>
HELO yourdomain.com
<<<
250 BAY004-MC6F11.hotmail.com (3.20.0.138) Hello [177.2.47.23]
>>>
MAIL FROM: <user@yourdomain.com>
<<<
250 user@yourdomain.com....Sender OK
>>>
RCPT TO: <thiago.sabin@hotmail.com>
<<<
250 thiago.sabin@hotmail.com 
>>>
RSET
<<<
554 Transaction failed
>>>
quit
<<<
```

As i can see the sender is okay and im trying to check my personal email thiago.sabin@hotmail.com and that's the answer...
This code is actually really simple but i can't make that "transaction" to work

Comment: Your ISP may be blocking it. Many ISPs block port 25 except to their SMTP relay, to prevent their customers from spamming.

Comment: Are you trying with the emails from the example without changing it? Of course example.com is not a valid server, or i'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: example.com is just a 'placeholder'. See http://www.example.com

Comment: updated my answer. The tl;dr is that it often just doesn't work and I would advise against using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code works as intended, as user@example.com, though it has a valid format, isn't a valid email address because example.com doesn't host a mail server. Google's example code contacts the receiving mail server to see if the given address exists on it. Try replacing user@example.com with another email address, like your own, and running the code again.

Edit: There are [many](http://www.spamresource.com/2010/11/smtp-address-validation-bad-idea.html) [posts](http://www.circleid.com/posts/sender_address_verification/) which say that using smtp verification is a bad idea. It seems to 1) not work on many smtp servers and 2) make it look like you're a spammer. I would advise just sticking to verifying that the email address is the proper format, and forgo the use of SMTP verification.

Comment: Yeah after running a few tests this smtp validation is "saying" that many valid emails arent valid... I am looking for some verification like when you write an email to a invalid adress like "sfshduifhasd@hotmail.com" and that message comes back saying it is invalid. I can't just check if the email format is right i need more "sureness" you know :c